# The action of an element in the center of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Assume the base field is Algebraically closed. Let $C(g)$ be the conjugacy class of an element $g$ in a finite group $G$ of order n and $χ$ be the character of an irreducible representation $ρ$. Prove that if $|C(g)|$ is relatively prime to $n$ and $χ(g)$ is nonzero, then $ρ(g)$ is the multiplication by a scalar.

Since the number of elements of a conjugacy class divides the order of the group, $|C(g)|$ must be $1$, and $g$ is in the center. Hence $g$ must act as a scalar multiplication. But why do I need $\chi(g)$ be nonzero? Is there anything wrong with my argument?

Comment: Argument seems fine to me. $\chi(g) \neq 0$ seems more to be a necessary byproduct of the conclusion, since (in this case) $\chi(g) = 0$ only if $\rho(g) = 0$, which is impossible.

Comment: So, nothing wrong with my arguments?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell.